# Unable to send fax in C# , the status shows pending

Tags: c#, asp.net, fax

I need to send a fax from my ASP.net application. I am using the code below to send a fax. All functions are working properly, but the fax status is showing as pending. Is there any way to solve this problem? ( I am not using fax modem )

```
    private void SendFaxTry(string DocumentName, string FileName, string RecipientName, string FaxNumber)
            {
                if (FaxNumber != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FaxServer faxServer = new FaxServer();
                        faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName);
                        FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);
                        faxDoc.RecipientName = RecipientName;
                        faxDoc.FaxNumber = FaxNumber;
                        faxDoc.DisplayName = DocumentName;
                        int Response = faxDoc.Send();
                        faxServer.Disconnect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception Ex)
                    {
                        errLbl.Text=(Ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the Response code from faxDoc.Send()?

Comment: each and every time response code is changing..  the code will be 69, 71, 73

Comment: `faxDoc.Send()` returns the job number for the fax.

Comment: I surfed for those response code, all codes are in the different meanings. what can i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Because they aren't response codes... they're job numbers.

Comment: @Amy...thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Dear @Amy , Kindly give your suggestion to solve this issue